# theme upgrade failing

Tags: updates, theme-twenty-eleven

The twenty eleven theme fails to update.
The error message is : failing to delete old theme.
For security reasons i dont want to give rights to every folders of the project.
What are the folder to give rights to for that action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the theme via cPanel by:

1. Browse `wp-content/themes/` using the file manager
2. Rename the folder named 'TwentyEleven' to 'TwentyEleven.Backup'
3. Download a fresh upgrade copy of T11 from WordPress.org theme repository
4. Upload the `.zip` theme file (what you just downloaded)
5. Extract the `.zip` file (it will make the folder 'TwentyEleven' again)
6. Your upgraded theme is ready

Hope it will automatically activate itself; if not, then in `wp-admin`, browse `Appearance` > `Themes`, and then reactivate (or deactivate and activate) Twenty Eleven theme.

**WARNING:** Upgrading a theme, by all the default and automatic means, will delete all the modifications and edits of codes, if made any.

Answer (score 2):

Themes are typically located in `wp-content/themes`. Additional theme directories might be registered, but it's more rare and unlikely for themes, bundled with core.

Note that WP has quite elaborate code for filesystem and when permissions are prohibitive asks for FTP/SSH credentials to work over, which you do not mention happening. It might indicate larger problem with you permissions and server configuration, that you might need to have hosting support look into.

Comment: it is useful , thanx